# Naming a variable based on user input Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to have a program where a variables name is determined by user input, like:

```
<html>
<script>
var name = prompt("User input")
var hold = prompt("More stuff")
var (Test + (name)) = (hold)
</script>
</html>
```

But this doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: `window['Test' + name] = hold;`

Comment: Please add an example

Comment: Why?  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Im trying to make a search for my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't name variables by a string. You can name properties on an object however.

```
var name = prompt("User input")
var hold = prompt("More stuff")
var obj = {};
obj['Test' + name] = (hold)
```